# zulegen vs. zunehmen

Tags: difference

- Haben die beide Wörter genau die selbe Bedeutung?
- Worin besteht der Unterschied zwischen ihnen?
- Verwendet man sie in gleichem Kontext?
- Wird eines dieser Wörter seltener/öfter benutzt als das andere?

In [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary) liest man:

**zulegen:**

> Bedeutungen:
>
> 1. größer werden
> 2. Gewicht: schwerer oder dicker werden
>
> Beispiele:
>
> Preis für Opec-Rohöl legt weiter zu.
>
> Die Investitionen in Immobilien legten um 6.2% zu.
>
> Es gibt viele Menschen, die gerne an Gewicht zulegen würden.

**zunehmen:**

> Bedeutungen:
>
> 1. größer werden
> 2. zunehmen an: eine Eigenschaft oder einen Besitz vergrößern
> 3. Gewicht: schwerer oder dicker werden
>
> Beispiele:
>
> Das Risiko für Altersarmut in Deutschland nimmt in den nächsten Jahren
>   weiter zu.
>
> Im Kampf um die irakische IS-Hochburg Mossul hat die Zahl ziviler
>   Opfer laut Amnesty International deutlich zugenommen.
>
> Er nahm ständig an Einfluss zu.
>
> Ich habe schon wieder ein Kilo zugenommen!

([eine Google Suche](https://www.google.ch/search?q=zulegen%20vs%20zunehmen&sourceid=ie8&rls=com.microsoft:de-CH:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&safe=on&safe=on&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=pkHKWeXDBsHCXqa9g8gC&safe=on&safe=on&gws_rd=ssl) nach einem möglichen Unterschied zwischen diesen Wörtern bringt nichts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Haben die beide Wörter genau die selbe Bedeutung?

Jein. Ja und nein. Wobei man zunehmen im Alltag eher mit Gewicht in Verbindung bringt - Wenn man "zunehmen" sagt hat man meist noch die Angabe von Gewicht dabei. "Wobei ich habe (an Gewicht) zugelegt" auch ohne Angabe von Gewicht möglich ist.

- Woraus besteht der Unterschied zwischen sie? (Zwischen *IHNEN*, den Wörtern, nicht sie)

Wie fast überall bei Wörtern, die man als alternative nutzen kann hängt es eben immer vom Verwendungsfall/Bezug ab.

- Verwendet man sie in gleichem Kontext? (*Sie*, die Wörter, ist hier korrekt verwendet worden)

Wie schon geschrieben, in den meisten Fällen können die Wörter einfach getauscht werden.
Allgemein wird aber "zulegen" eher im Bereicht von Werten/Prozent/Messungen genutzt und das reine "zunehmen" mit Bezug auf das Körpergewicht.

- Ist ein dieser Wörter seltener/öfter benutzt als der andere?

"Zulegen" wird im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch seltener verwendet als zugenommen (von meinem *reinen Gefühl* als "native german" her).

Gerne noch andere Meinungen und Ansichten dazu, dies ist wie gesagt nur meine persönliche Meinung dazu.

Comment: Didn't want to be a "dick" to copy mistakes and point them out - also in most cases can't explain these mistakes by myself, I just see them as sounding "weird".